# LINQ to SQL group by to a blank row of data?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following code in sql:

```
SELECT "Field 1" AS fullname, null  AS limsuser_id
   UNION 
SELECT fullname, limsuser_id from table1
   UNION
SELECT "Field 2" AS fullname, null  AS limsuser_id
   UNION 
SELECT fullname, limsuser_id from table2
```

Basically, "Field 1" and "Field 2" acts as a header.
Now, this returns a dataset on ASP.net side.

However, when someone clicks on "Full name" on sorting the dataset, then data gets sorted with "Field 1" and "Field 2" also.

Before Sorting:

```
Field 1
Jason Z   | 25
Anthony P | 21

Field 2
Shane | 24
Damon | 23
```

After sort:

```
Anthony P | 21
Damon     | 23
Field 1
Field 2
Jason Z   | 25
Shane     | 24
```

Expected Result:

```
Field 1
Anthony P | 21
Jason Z   | 25
Field 2
Damon | 23
Shane | 24
```

How can I do a group by on dataset with "Field 1" and "Field 2" using linq?
This is a simplified sql. I don't have liberty to change sql query.

Comment: First of all, if you are binding two different sets of data in a single control then this is not a good design practice. In this approach, you will have to apply patches in code. Better return two objects from LINQ & bind them in the different control.

Comment: its a legacy code and have no control over sql query.

Comment: then create two List<SomeType>, one will hold Field 1 data & other will have Field  2 data. Bind both lists with different controls.

Comment: for `Field 1` and `Field 2` the `limsuser_id` is always null?

Comment: yes, limuser_id is always null for field 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a field that shows which table you have taken them from:

```
SELECT "Field 1" AS fullname, null  AS limsuser_id, 1 as [order]
   UNION 
SELECT fullname, limsuser_id, 1 as [order] from table1 
   UNION
SELECT "Field 2" AS fullname, null  AS limsuser_id, 2 as [order]
   UNION 
SELECT fullname, limsuser_id, 2 as [order] from table2
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
var result = yourItems.OrderByDescending(x=> x.fullname == "Field 1" || x.fullname == "Field 2")
    .ThenBy(x=> x.fullname)
    .GroupBy(x=> x.order);
```

`.OrderByDescending(x=> x.fullname == "Field 1" || x.fullname == "Field 2")` ensures that `Field 1` and `Field 2` will stand on top of their groups no matter what their aphabetical order is.

`.ThenBy(x=> x.fullname)` will then sort it by `fullname`

then you can GroupBy on `order` field.

Or if you have null id for only `Field 1` and `Field 2` you can do this:

```
var result = yourItems.OrderByDescending(x=> x.limsuser_id  == null)
    .ThenBy(x=> x.fullname)
    .GroupBy(x=> x.order);
```

Comment: doing an order by will lose the information: Field 1 contains "Anthony and Jason". Field 2 contains "Damon and Shane". If I do orderby, I'll get Anthony, Damon, Field1, Field2,

Comment: I had got the whole question wrong, have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: let me try and see if can get order from sql.

Comment: @Gauravsa I also added some extra code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

New method suggested by @Ashkan will work. But for your requirement you may not need grouping. Just add column to identify the order with different values for each of 4 sets

```
SELECT "Field 1" AS fullname, null  AS limsuser_id, 1 AS order_no
   UNION 
SELECT fullname, limsuser_id, 2 AS order_no from table1 
   UNION
SELECT "Field 2" AS fullname, null  AS limsuser_id, 3 AS order_no
   UNION 
SELECT fullname, limsuser_id, 4 AS order_no from table2
```

Then do ordering in Linq

```
var orderedSet = items.OrderBy(x=> x.order_no).ThenBy(x=> x.fullname);
```

Comment: I had actually thought of that, but this has a problem with group by

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Seeing the expected result in the question Group by may not be required. Questioner just put his thoughts if he can use Group by

Comment: For descending, var orderedSet = items.OrderBy(x=> x.order_no).ThenByDescending(x=> x.fullname);